# mysql array in Where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a text file contains around 300 lines, each line contains first 3 characters of the postal codes. like this,

```
M2X
I5D
T8I
O0P
K6R
```

I am looking for the best way to use this list in my query `Where` clause to match all the records from a table where first 3 digits is in this list.

How can I ready txt file then create an array then use it in `Where`

Update my answer:

```
WHERE POST regexp '^(M2X|I5D|T8I|.....)'

WHERE POST rlike '^(M2X|I5D|T8I|.....)'
```

Comment: What server side language are you using?

Comment: what you mean server side language?

Comment: I actually just meant programming language. Bill has the best approach, but you will need to put all your postal codes into a string first.

Comment: I use powershell to convert my list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the SQL `IN ( )` predicate for this.

You'd want it to look like:

```
WHERE post_code IN ('M2X','I5D','T8I','O0P','K6R',...)
```

Converting a file of text lines into that format can be done in a variety of scripting languages. For example, sed and awk:

```
sed -e "s/.*/'&'/" postal_codes.csv | awk 'BEGIN { ORS="," } { print }' | sed "s/,$//"
'M2X','I5D','T8I','O0P','K6R'
```

---

If you only want the first three characters of your data to match the postal code, in other words as if they are prefixes, you can try this:

```
WHERE LEFT(post_code, 3) IN ('M2X','I5D','T8I','O0P','K6R',...)
```

That has the disadvantage of not being able to search using an index.

Another option is to use pattern-matching, which will use the index if you search on the prefix. But this makes the query rather long:

```
WHERE post_code LIKE 'M2X%'
   OR post_code LIKE 'I5D%'
   OR post_code LIKE 'T8I%'
   OR post_code LIKE 'O0P%'
   OR post_code LIKE 'K6R%'
   OR ...
```

Or you can load the set of 300 post codes (with the `%` wildcard at the end) into a temp table, and do it with a JOIN:

```
SELECT ...
FROM mytable JOIN tmp_post_codes
  ON post_code LIKE post_code_pattern
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint,  it does not work. I think my question was not clear, my table contains the full postal code like `M2X R4T`, my list is only contains the first 3 digits of the postal code in each line. I am trying to pull all the records from my table that postal code matches the first 3 digits in my list.

Comment: figured out    `where postal_code regexp '^[M2X|I5D|T8I|.....]'`   or `where postal_code rlike '^[M2X|I5D|T8I|.....]'`

Comment: Good to know there are multiple way to do this